# How to set a rules action to write vote/ratings

Tags: drupal-7, rules, voting, voting-system

How can I set an action in rules to enter a value in voting or ratings? The voting rules module settings allow for voting to be an event, but not a reaction. I select "node:vote-results" as the data to enter. However I get an error message "The selected data property doesn't support writing."

Comment: Seems we have to write custom action...